# Reading messages from a chat on Telegram using python 3.11 and telethon

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I do apologize for the simplicity of the question.
I'm trying to read messages from a chat on Telegram using python and telethon. After consulting the documentation, Stack Overflow and other websites, here are two of the many codes I tried.

```
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient

api_id = '#####991'
api_hash = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxee8df'

chat_name = 'xxxxxxess_Bot'

with TelegramClient('sync', api_id, api_hash) as client:
    for message in client.iter_messages(chat_name):
        print(message.sender_id, ':', message.text)
```

And

```
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient

api_id = '#####991'
api_hash = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxee8df'

chat_name = 'xxxxxxess_Bot'

phone_number = '+21#########03'

client = TelegramClient(phone_number, api_id, api_hash)
client.start()
chat_entity = client.get_entity(chat_name)

async def read_messages():
    messages = await client.get_messages(chat_entity)
    for message in messages:
        if not message.read:
            print(message.id, message.text)

with client:
    client.loop.run_until_complete(read_messages())

client.disconnect()
```

It's returning nothing, not even an error, although I can clearly see 427 unread messages on the Telegram app on my phone.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the chat_name wasn't doing it. Maybe I entered the wrong chat_name. So, I used the link of the chat instead.

Here is the code that worked for me:

```
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient

api_id = '#####991'
api_hash = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxee8df'

with TelegramClient('sync', api_id, api_hash) as client:
    chat_entity = client.get_entity('t.me/#########sdz_bot')
    for message in client.iter_messages(chat_entity):
        print(message.sender_id, ':', message.text)
```

This will read all the messages from that particular chat.

I still don't know how to get only the unread messages though.